# Is nesting React Context Provider and consuming those with useContext a problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What problem can I encounter with a deep nested React context provider?

```js
const AllContextProvider = props => {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <NotifProvider>
          <TimelineProvider>
            <CertProvider>
              <MenusProvider>
              {props.children}
              </MenusProvider>
            </CertProvider>
          </TimelineProvider>
        </NotifProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </UserProvider>
  );
};
```

And consuming those nested providers with a Context dependencie like this :

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
import { useLocalStoragePerUser } from "./useLocalStoragePerUser";

const MenusContext = React.createContext();
const { Provider } = MenusContext;

const MenusProvider = props => {
  // Is this context dependencie always "re-trigger" the Menu Context Provider?
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);

  // Menus Context
  const [menu, setMenu] = useLocalStoragePerUser( "menus", {
      icons: false,
      labels: true,
      leftMenu: true,
    },
    user
  );

  return (
    <Provider value={{ menu, setMenu}} >
      {props.children}
    </Provider>
  );
};

export { MenusProvider, MenusContext };
```

Is this context dependencie always "re-trigger" the Menu Context Provider?
=> especially concerning useless re-renders?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Having nested Contexts will not cause any issues in your code. In the above case if you subscribe to `UserContext` in `MenuContext`, the `MenuContext` will only re-render when the `UserContext` has changed the value supplied to its provider. However unless the MenuContext changes the value it passes to the `MenuContext Provider` its children who are subscribing to `MenuContext` will not re-render and also no other children will be re-rendered

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { UserProvider } from "./UserProvider";
import { ThemeProvider } from "./ThemeProvider";
import { MenusProvider } from "./MenuProvider";

import "./styles.css";
function Child() {
  console.log("Child render");
  return <div>Menus Child</div>;
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <UserProvider>
        <ThemeProvider>
          <MenusProvider>
            <Child />
          </MenusProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </UserProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can see a **[DEMO in the codeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/93l66qjwzo)**

> **P.S.** However you must make sure that you are not creating a new object
>   while passing the value to a Provider otherwise everytime the Provider
>   re-renders all children which subscribe to its context will re-render

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do a demo for that question. I play with it and ... that's it, I'm starting to understand. I play with the user state: `const [user, setUser] = useState("A")` and  `const [user, setUser] = useState({name: "A"})` to fully understand when the Provider/SubContext/Childs re-render.

Comment: I left it out intentionally to show that changing theme provider value doesn't cause its children to re-render

Comment: Yes, Sorry to have deleted my remark (which was: "why not using 'theme' variable in the children). But precisely, in this case ... a new Object is still created in the ThemeProvider menu value although no re-render occurs in none of the children ? Is this not the opposite of your P.S. remark?

Comment: That is because no one is subscribing to ThemeProvider, if any of the component does, it will re-render whenever ThemeProvider re-renders

Comment: Perfect! Merci beaucoup

Comment: In your DEMO, the `menu` Object is not actually passed in `MenusProvider`. So, I suppose `<Provider value={{ menu }}>{props.children}</Provider>` is better ... which correctly re-render the subscribing consumer when the `UserContext` change the `MenusProvider` ?